# ssl socket - Get the real number of bytes of the original message(without the encryption)

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, encryption

I have a server client code that transfers files in python using sockets.

I was thinking about using SSL, but there is one simple problem.
I am using the Buffsize of socket.recv() in order to know how much
bytes were transferred until now.

If I add SSL now, each message size would grow (because of the encryption) and I won't be able to tell how much of the original file was transferred.

Is there a way to get the original message size after the encryption?
or do you have another method of knowing when the file has been completely transferred?

Comment: In principle there is no reason why the same method you use for determining file size for cleartext blocking sockets would not work for ssl-based sockets. The data you receive from SSLSocket.recv() is the decrypted data, the SSL library should have taken care of everything for you. Note: if you are using nonblocking sockets then things are much more complicated.

Comment: I am not using nonblocking sockets so it should work?
The amout of the file's data I receive in each recv() won't change?

Comment: The amount of data received in each recv() should be irrelevant anyway. If your protocol depends on that always being the same it is an incorrect protocol, with or without SSL.